# iOS Fix TableView To Bottom Like Messages App

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, tableview

So this is completely out of my area of (expertise?) so I figured I'd ask it and see if anyone more experienced could give me a yes or no answer.

So, I'm using Appcelerator Titanium to build an app that has many tableviews. I am looking to build it so that some of the tableViews start at the bottom and I can scroll UP instead of scrolling DOWN to start, exactly the same way as the "Messages" app does on the iPhone.

The way it works is content loads in and it's automatically loaded in with the tableview fixed to the bottom, then you can scroll upwards to see older posts.

I cannot find a way to do this in appcelerator other than create the tableview, load the data, then scroll it to the bottom (which obviously has that snapping). I can hide the tableview, scroll to bottom, then show the tableview, but again... not ideal.

Now the question... **Is it possible using the standard iOS SDK (Not appcelerator) to do set a table to fix to the bottom instead of the top?** If not, i'll have to find a work around somehow. If it is, I'd like to try to build it into a titanium module if at all possible...

Anyways, thanks! And hopefully this is a simple answer for some of you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, it really is quite trivial.  Something like this would work just fine:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   //place this at the bottom of your viewDidLoad method, or in any method that initially reloads the table
    NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: myArray.count-1 inSection: 0];
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated: NO]
}
```

Comment: That's a great way to do it. As the UITableView inherits from the UIScrollView you could also take a look at `-scrollRectToVisible:animated` and `setContentOffset:animated:` of the UIScrollView.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks!I really wish I new more on how to read/write that code haha I'm more of a rails/javascript kinda guy. Anyways, this is extremely helpful. I'm going to see if Appcelerator already has something like this available in their sdk but, from what I see I don't really see a similar method.It's great to know that it is possible! Just so I'm clear, this method will allow the table to stay fixed to the bottom when it loads? Is it possible (with this or a similar method) to also have it remain fixed to the bottom when new tableViewRows or Sections are appended to it? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, too late to edit I guess... I meant to say "prepended" not "appended" although I guess both apply. If I add a row to the bottom I'd want it to scroll to the new bottom. If I prepend a row to the top, I'd want it to stay fixed to the bottom. Hope that makes sense and I'm not overcomplicating it!

Comment: Like I said, whenever you reload the table and you want it to scroll to the bottom, call this code here after the reload.

Comment: It's what I'm here for.  You good people keep my rep at absurdly high levels :)

Comment: This code working fine.. But while scrolling table view position changed is there any restriction for that.?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to scroll in viewDidLoad, but after view controller appears, i can see the the begining of table on view appear.

I've found the better place for the initial scrolling.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = MAX(0, [self.chatTableView numberOfSections] - 1);
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = MAX(0, [self.chatTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1);
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
   [self.chatTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I t all depends on when your table loads data and if you are using auto layout.